# Python 3.10 match multiple arguments

Tags: python

I have 3 conditions, each one in a variable (a, b, and c)

I want to match the order and their values on a `match` statement

```
def main():
    a = "ABC"
    b = 2
    c = 3

    match a, b, c:
        case "ABC" | 2 | 3:
            print("match all")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: `a, b, c` is a tuple. So the `case` pattern has to be a tuple of patterns.

Comment: I changed it to a tuple, and it didn't work. I am using Python 3.10.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `case` pattern should be structured just like the value you're matching, so it should be a tuple.

```
match (a, b, c):
    case ("ABC", 2, 3):
        print("match all")
```

Comment: I can't test it because I don't have python 3.10.

Comment: @JRose the match/case construction is a relatively recent update; your version of python might not have it